# iOS Video playsinline not always playing inline in swift app

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, youtube

I use `YouTube` api to show `Youtube` on `Ios`. I don't have a problem showing it, but when I click on the video, it's constantly changing to the `full screen`, and this is a problem that works normally with the `Android`, but only don't work for `Ios`

**html file**

```html
<div id="video_iframe"></div>
```

**js file**

```js
var tag = document.createElement("script");
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player("video_iframe", {
    height: "720",
    width: "720",
    videoId: video_code,
    playerVars: {
      controls: "0", 
      start: video_start,
      end: video_end,
      mute: "0", 
      rel: "0", 
      playsinline: "1"
    }
  });
}
```

Has anyone solved the same problem as me? I am using `WKWebview`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youtube iFramePlayerApi says :

> This parameter controls whether videos play inline or fullscreen in an
>   HTML5 player on iOS. Valid values are:
>
> 0: This value causes fullscreen playback. This is currently the
>   default value, though the default is subject to change.
>
> 1: This value causes **inline playback for UIWebViews created with the
>   allowsInlineMediaPlayback property set to TRUE.**

set `allowsInlineMediaPlayback` to `true` for your `WKWebView`